# $11^{-1}$ modulo $91$ is $58$. Why?

Tags: calculus, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am reading wiki article about [Quadratic Sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_sieve#Partial_relations_and_cycles) and it says

$11^{-1}$ modulo $91$ is $58$

Why? How is it been calculated?

Comment: If your question is more about the *how* than the *why*, have a look at [modular multiplicative inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse), and in particular look at the part about the *Extended Euclidean Algorithm*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason $58 = 11^{-1} \pmod{91}$ is 
$$58 \cdot 11 = 638 = 7 \cdot 91 + 1 \implies 58 \cdot 11 \equiv 638 \equiv 1 \pmod{91}$$

The reason $11$ has an inverse $\pmod{91}$ is that $\gcd(11, 91) = 1$.

To calculate the inverse, we use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm). First, we use the Euclidean Algorithm to solve for $\gcd(11, 91)$.
\begin{align*}
91 & = 8 \cdot 11 + 3\\
11 & = 3 \cdot 3 + 2\\
3 & = 1 \cdot 2 + 1\\
2 & = 2 \cdot 1
\end{align*}
Working backwards, we express $1$ as a linear combination of $11$ and $91$.
\begin{align*}
1 & = 3 - 1 \cdot 2\\
  & = 3 - 1(11 - 3 \cdot 3)\\
  & = 4 \cdot 3 - 1 \cdot 11\\
  & = 4(91 - 8 \cdot 11) - 1 \cdot 11\\
  & = 4 \cdot 91 - 33 \cdot 11
\end{align*}
Hence, 
$$-33 \cdot 11 = 1 - 4 \cdot 91 \implies -33 \cdot 11 \equiv 1 \pmod{91}$$
Thus, $-33 \equiv 11^{-1} \pmod{91}$.  Moreover, any number of the form $-33 + 91t$ is an inverse of $11 \pmod{91}$ since 
$$
11(-33 + 91t) = -363 + 11t \cdot 91 = 1 - 364 + 11t \cdot 91 = 1 + 91(11t - 4)$$ 
Thus, $11(-33 + 91t) \equiv 1 \pmod{91} \implies -33 + 91t \equiv 11^{-1} \pmod{91}$.
In particular, if $t = 1$, we obtain 
$$11^{-1} \equiv -33 + 91 \equiv 58 \pmod{91}$$

Answer (score 4):

$$11\cdot 58 = 638 \equiv 1 \pmod{91}$$

In other words, $11^{-1} = 58$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{91}$.

$\mathbb{Z}_{91} = \{\bar{0},...,\bar{90}\}$ where $\bar{a} = \{x\in \mathbb{Z}|x \equiv a \pmod{91}$}. Now $11^{-1}$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{91}$ is 58 since $$11\cdot58 = 58\cdot 11 = 1 \text{ in } \mathbb{Z}_{91} $$

And this is how we define the inverse. But of course we have $11^{-1} = \frac{1}{11}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, and you must be careful not to confuse the two.

Comment: Can you provide explanation to what you just wrote. May be you can link me to an article about this.

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman, he showed $11\cdot 58 = 638 \equiv 1 \pmod{91}$. now, as $\gcd (11,91)=1$ you can divide both side by  $11$, that does not harm $91$. So, thus you get the required result.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey I don't get it. What I type in my calculator $\frac{1,11} \mod{58}$ I am getting a number smaller than 1. I am building trying to implement this algorithm in Java, so I need to be able to do this calculation. I don't get it just yet

Comment: @Ilya_Gazman By definition, the number $11^{-1}$ is the number $x$ such that $11 \cdot x \equiv 1 \pmod {91}$. So this is why $58$ works. I don't think there exists a "smart" algorithm for doing this except trying all the possble values. Note that some numbers may not have an inverse

Comment: In particular, $a$ in $\mathbb{Z}_b$ has an inverse iff $\gcd(a,b) = 1$.

Comment: @Ant: There certainly _is_ a smart way to calculate the [modular multiplicative inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse). The usual way is to use the extended Euclidean algorithm mentioned earlier by Tormod Haugland. This is (usually) taught fairly early in an introductory number theory course.

Comment: @PM2Ring I stand corrected.  Thank you :-)

Comment: Without any theory we have, modulo $91 , $  $ 11.58\equiv 22.29\equiv (-69)(-62)\equiv 2.3.23.31\equiv 2.23.93\equiv 2.23.2\equiv 92\equiv 1.$ A more sophisticated way, about 25 centuries old (Euclid) as mentioned by PM 2Ring (above) is the algorithm for finding integers $x,y$ such that $11 x+91 y=1$. And then $11 x \equiv 1 \pmod {91}.$